# Gitignore being ignored

Tags: git

I am having an issue with files that should be ignored being added when I do an add .

I programmatically initialise a repo and then create a .gitignore and README and commit them.
Then when I touch a file that should be ignored and do a "git add ." it shows up as a new file and gets added on the next commit, I'm sure I'm doing something pretty stupid. This is what the workflow would look like

```
mkdir testrepo
cd testrepo
git init
<Create Java.gitignore and README>
git add Java.gitignore
git add README.md
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
touch bob.java
touch bob.class
git add .
```

and then it shows

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
 (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   bob.class
    new file:   bob.java
```

This is the `Java.gitignore` I'm using

```
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

Comment: Did you really name the file `Java.gitignore`?

Comment: Yeah, rather than rewrite the files I was just copying them from the installation directory of my application and I was  copying the whole filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be called, literally, `.gitignore`. `Java.gitignore` is being, well, ignored by git because the file is misnamed.

Do a quick `mv Java.gitignore .gitignore` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct? hate to be that guy, but...it's points, yo.